# Responding with a custom HTTP code with GraphQL Yoga from a mutation resolver

Tags: express, graphql, prisma

I'm working on a mutation resolver using GraphQL Yoga and using Prisma for my back-end. The mutation is for doing authentication and returning a JWT on successful login. The mutation currently looks like this:

```
loginEmployer: async (_, args, context, info) => {
  const employer = await context.prisma.query.employer({
    where: {
      name: args.name,
    }
  })
  const match = await bcrypt.compare(args.password, employer.hashedPassword);
  if (match) {
    return jwt.sign(employer, jwtSecret);
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

The algorithm is fairly simple as you can see: Find an employer with the matching name, compare the stored hashed password with the incoming using bcrypt, and return a signed jwt if there's a match. Pretty standard stuff.

However in the case there is no match, or if there is no employer matching the name, I'd like to respond with a 403. In express I'd simply do `res.status(403).send({error: "No such username/password"})` but with GraphQL Yoga I'm a bit lost and couldn't find any documentation for how to do this.

Thanks for any replies sorting this out or pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abhi from prisma here!

In GraphQL Yoga you can pass a `context` factory which contains the request and the response!

Here's an example!

`new GraphQLServer({ 
        typeDefs, 
        resolvers,
        context: ({ req, res, ...rest }) => {
          // pass things down in context!
          return { req, res, userId: req.headers.userid };
        },
    })`

Then in your resolver, just pull `res` out of the context object.

Now this does work fine and well, but here's a github issue on a similiar thing that had some other opinions on this: https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/issues/71

Comment: Aha, so in the context object I have access to the entire express api? res.status(403).send({blabla}) should work?

Comment: Also would is simply be possible to do `context.res.status(403); throw new Error('blabla')`? It seems throwing from yoga returns the error message and doesn't disrupt anything, but the status code is 200 so I'd just like to set it to 403 before throwing.

Comment: In case anyone else is struggling with anything similar: The props on the incoming parameter into context are called "request" and "response". Simply naming them ({ req, res }) on the way in will not work. Needs to be ({ request, response }). Other than that, works perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Following @Lars Holdaas - It took me far too long to work out the answer. But the context parameters are `request` and `response`.

If you use req/res, it does not work. So a more accurate example:

```
new GraphQLServer({ 
        typeDefs, 
        resolvers,
        context: ({ request, response, ...rest }) => {
          return { 
             req: request, 
             res: response, 
             userId: request.headers.userid
          };
        },
    })
```

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much what I ended up with as well. I guess `userId: request.headers.userid` though